# Can find Xpath even with the absolute path

Tags: python, selenium, class, xpath

Want to get the Date of a google search.
I copied the Xpath from Chrome-Xpath-Finder and it still cant find the element, how is this possible? With absolute path:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=datum")
xpath_abs = "//html/body/div[7]/div/div[10]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/span"
datum_heute = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath_abs)
```

I didnt wanted to finde it over absolute path, since it has an class i tried this:

```
xpath_class = "//div[@class = 'vk_bk dDoNo FzvWSb']/span"
datum_heute = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath_class)
```

But cant finde it, how is it that i cant finde it even with the copied absolute path?

Here is a picture for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Which element is that? You are not able to find it cause see this class `vk_bk dDoNo FzvWSb` it is dynamic in nature so every time your script runs it will be changed.

Comment: The picture above explains it better. I realoaded the Browser a few times and it didnt change yet. So it would over time? Its just a test anyway, want to get it to work with xpath class, but even the copied absolute path dont work.

Comment: I tried your xPath and its working perfectly. I am able to print the date value. Please try by adding some wait statements.

Comment: hmm, it not working by me. I have driver.implicitly_wait(10) at the start.

Comment: After capturing xPath, are you printing `datum_heute`? If yes, what error you are getting?

Comment: now it works, didnt know what the problem was

Answer (score 1):

Probably the craziest search I've made `//span[@data-dobid='hdw']//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div`
[DOM Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yEfl.png) But I would say, using selenium on Google is always going to be flaky due to the randomness in the attributes that Google has. It is always better to use API instead.

Here is the code in execution:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=datum")
time.sleep(3)
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@data-dobid='hdw']//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//parent::Div")
print(x.text)
```

Output:

```
datum
/ˈdeɪtəm/
noun
1.
a piece of information.
"the fact is a datum worth taking into account"
2.
a fixed starting point of a scale or operation.
"an accurate datum is formed by which other machining operations can be carried out"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You have a different search result than me. I added a picture above. What browser did you use? I am new, what do you mean with API in this case? Can you show me the same output result with an API?

Comment: @Fuorb I used Chrome browser. You may find Google API [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). To explain the API would be out of scope in this comment. I request you to Google out and learn about them. I am pasting here a link that describes what an api is, but explore on your own if it gets technical [API](https://project-open-data.cio.gov/api-basics/)

Comment: @AnandGautam I am bit confused with your answer. He is using google in his country so based on the screenshot provided by OP, the term detum means date. You searched datum in your country and found different results, based on that you constructed a xPath which is irrelevant to  the question. You mentioned "It is always better to use API instead of Google" what is this statement stands for? When you need to perform a testing using browser then what is the point of using API?

Comment: @Nandan, My apologies. I was not aware it would result in a different way.However the result maybe different, but the element I think would be intact and since I haven't use any text based locators, it should still work. Having said that, Google browser automation would always be challenging and quite unreliable as the element attributes are deliberately randomized. What may work now may not work in the very near future, and hence I suggested the use of API. If it is for practice purpose, it's ok, but if you are trying to scrape and want to use the code in future, it would be futile

Comment: When I provided the answer, the picture was not provided, so I just relied on the elements as provided.

Comment: You can just search with word `date` and you will get the same `DOM` what OP was provided.

Comment: Here are some more ways to find the date:
`//div[contains(@class, 'card-section')]`

`//span[contains(text(), 'Date')]//parent::div`

`//div[@data-hveid='CAIQAQ']//div`

All these 3 locators point to the date

Comment: You could try //div[contains(@class,'lr_container')]/div[@jsslot][3]